# Why is the OnClick event fired when I click a TextView without android:onClick in Android Studio?

Tags: android

The following code is from the project architecture-samples, you can see it [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples).

The `LinearLayout` has an `android:onClick` event, and the `TextView` control has no `android:onClick` event.

I think that the `OnClick` event will be fired when I click the left sapce rather than `CheckBox` or `TextView` controls occupied. But in fact an `OnClick` event is fired when I click on `TextView`, why?

BTW, an `OnClick` event will not be fired when I click on `CheckBox`.

**task_item.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.widget.CompoundButton" />

        <variable
            name="task"
            type="com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.data.Task" />

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.tasks.TasksViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_item_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_item_padding"
        android:onClick="@{()-> viewmodel.openTask(task.id)}">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/complete_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="@{(view) -> viewmodel.completeTask(task, ((CompoundButton)view).isChecked())}"
            android:checked="@{task.completed}" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:text="@{task.titleForList}"
            app:completedTask="@{task.completed}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: All child with no set onClick will be mark no focusable, so it will be fire onClick of parent

Comment: To prevent this behavior, I recommend you set focusable and clickable = true for title_text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Views have the `android:clickable="false"` property unless they are given an onClick listener or the property is explicitly declared to be `"true"`.

When you have overlapping views and one is clicked and it has `android:clickable="false"`, it will ignore click events, so any view beneath it that is *not* ignoring click events will handle the click. In your case if the TextView is clicked it ignores it, and the LinearLayout's onClick will fire. To prevent this behavior, add `android:clickable="true"` and `android:focusable="true"` to the TextView. That will make it accept clicks but do nothing, instead of passing the clicks to the view beneath it.